# PostGIS <-> operator does not return true distance

Tags: postgis, postgresql, knn

I want to find the closest polygon to a point. My idea was to use the `<->` operator for it. According to the [docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.2/geometry_distance_knn.html) it says:

> For PostgreSQL below 9.5 only gives centroid distance of bounding
>   boxes and for PostgreSQL 9.5+, does true KNN distance search giving
>   true distance between geometries, and distance sphere for geographies.

I use PostGIS 2.2 and PostgreSQL 9.5.7. So, the `<->` operator  should use the "true KNN distance", but it does not: it still orders by the centroid_distance.

[image]

```
SELECT id,
       ST_Distance(my_point.geom, 
                   my_polygons.geom) AS real_distance,
       ST_Distance(my_point.geom,  
                   ST_Centroid(my_polygons.geom)) AS centroid_distance



FROM (
    SELECT 'blue' AS id, ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(0 3, 2 3,  2 4, 0 4 ,0 3)'),4326) AS geom
    UNION
    SELECT 'green' AS id,  ST_Polygon(ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(2 0, 8 0 , 8 2, 2 2 ,2 0)'),4326) AS geom

) AS my_polygons,

(
    SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Point(1, 1),4326) AS geom
) AS my_point

ORDER BY my_point.geom <-> my_polygons.geom
```

Result:

```
|       | real_distance | centroid_distance |
---------------------------------------------
| blue  |       2       |        2.5        |
| green |       1       |        4          |
```

I expected that the `<->` operator orders the polygons according to the real_distance and not the centroid_distance.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The <-> operator is finding the closest polygon by the kNN distance and ordering results accordingly, but your actual distance metric is being determined by ST_Distance, which will definitely return the distance to the nearest point on exterior of the polygon, not the centroid. It is a bit hard to tell without some raw numbers, though.

Comment: Can you add a field `ST_Distance(ST_Point(1,2)::geography, ST_Centroid(my_polygons.geom)) AS cent_distance` to be sure of this?

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça do you need more information? Which numbers shall I provide?

Comment: Well, you say the answer is incorrect, but it is impossible for us to test without some geometries and the expected results. The query itself looks ok.

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça I updated my question. Can you explain this behavior of PostGIS? Thanks :-)

Comment: I can't. When I run your code, I get green first and then blue, as you would expect. What happens if you put ASC at the end of the ORDER BY. I realize  that it shouldn't be the case, but just to check.

Comment: When I put the ASC I get the same result as before. Which Postgres/PostGIS version are you using?

Comment: Perhaps excessive information, but: PostgreSQL 9.5.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 5.3.1-14ubuntu2) 5.3.1 20160413, 64-bit
 and POSTGIS="2.3.2 r15302" GEOS="3.5.0-CAPI-1.9.0 r4084" PROJ="Rel. 4.9.2, 08 September 2015" GDAL="GDAL 2.1.3, released 2017/20/01" LIBXML="2.9.3" LIBJSON="0.11.99" RASTER, ie, 9.5.6 and 2.3.2 :-) I have also tried on 9.4 and 9.6, with 2.2 and 2.3, and get the same, ie, correct result. Very bizarre.

Comment: OK. It seems that PostGIS 2.2.2 does not use "real KNN distance" - whereas 2.3.2 does support it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61991/discussion-between-coding-bird-and-john-powell-aka-barca).